# create two nft collections from one smart contract (erc1155) in OpenSea

Tags: ethereum, smartcontracts, nft

I want to list two collections on Opensea but instead of creating two smart contracts for that, I want to create only one (to save gas fees of uploading a contract).

the only two ways I found to create a collection on OpenSea are:

1. import an existing contract and it will automatically detect all the minted NFTs and display them.
2. create items manually with OpenSea UI and add them to a collection that is also created from the UI (without any code required)

is there a way to import an existing contract and select prefixes of ids or a range of ids (of minted NFTs)

and show them as one collection in OpenSea? or there is another marketplace that supports this?

Comment: Did you happen to find an answer to this by any chance?

Comment: i found a project that used that functionality- called "art block" [link to opensea](https://opensea.io/category/art-blocks), it has multiple collections in one smart contract using custom fields in the metadata that opensea can parse but they are not in the official documentation and I think that its implementation especially for that project. If someone find a way to do that now i will be happy to know